# Working of erase keyword in string in stl?

Tags: c++, string, stl, erase

I wrote this code to remove consonants from string but my answer is not correct. So what change should i make in this code to make it work correctly. Further more when i remove the space character i.e. last element from unordered set then the output was unexpected to me. So please help me understanding what is going on in this code??

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   unordered_set<char> a={'a','e','i','o','O','u','U','A','E','I',' '};

   string s="what are you doing";

   string ::iterator it;
   for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
      if(a.find(*it)==a.end()){
         s.erase(it);}
    }   

    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are changing the string while looping, that doesn't work since you invalidate your  iterator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually `std::string::erase` doc does not say it invalidates iterators https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase hmm

Comment: Recommendation: Use caution with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) and `using namespace std;` ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Use greater caution when you use both because they magnify some of each other's worst effects.

Comment: Why downvote and close request? OP created [mcve] and provided enough information IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has issue, when you remove symbol

```
s.erase(it);
```

and later increase it by loop you skip a symbol and also may go over the end of string. Possible solution to fix your code:

```
for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();){
   if(a.find(*it)==a.end())
      it = s.erase(it);
   else
      ++it;
 }
```

Note1: usually in STL containers when erasing element by iterator invalidate that iterator. Though documentation for [`std::string::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) does not say that any iterator invalidated and possibly it is not the case here. Anyway code I provided will work in any case and with any container and solves your issue as well.

But better to use [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom using `std::remove_if()`:

```
   s.erase( std::remove_if( s.begin(), s.end(), [a] ( char c ){ return a.count(c) == 0; } ), s.end() );
```

Note2: it is not a good idea to include "bits/stdc++.h"

[live example](https://ideone.com/8iE0LT)

Comment: must be a failure in cppreference, for example an `end()` iterator is certainly invalidated....

Comment: @user463035818 right, still not clear if `it` is invalidated. Looks like deserves another question in SO.

Comment: The remove/erase-idiom has linear worst-case complexity. For the other approach it is quadratic. Thus, it is ill-advised to use it and the discussion on whether iterators get invalidated is kind of moot. Note, that the end of the string changes. As strings are contiguous a copy of the former iterator points beyond the end of the range and is clearly invalid.